# Duplicate id when creating a dialog in OpenUI5

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5

I need help with OpenUI5. I created button in View and by clicking on button it creates Dialog window and throws an error so I cant proceed to functionality of the Dialog.

Button in view:

```
<m:Button text="{i18n>RESULTS_CHANCES_SEND_EMAIL}"
          class="sapUiMediumMarginBegin results-button"
          tap="sendToEmail"
          press="sendToEmail"
          icon="sap-icon://email">
```

Function in Controller:

```
sendToEmail: function() {

    var email = new Dialog({
      title: 'שליחת תוצאות לדוא"ל',
      type: 'Message',
      content: [
        new Input('submitEmailInput', {
          liveChange: function (oEvent) {
            var sText = oEvent.getParameter('value');
            var parent = oEvent.getSource().getParent();

            parent.getBeginButton().setEnabled(sText.length > 0);
          },
          width: '100%',
          placeholder: 'דואר אלקטרוני'
        })
      ],
      beginButton: new Button({
        text: 'שליחה',
        enabled: false,
        icon: 'sap-icon://email',
        press: function () {

          //var sText = sap.ui.getCore().byId('submitEmailInput').getValue();
          //MessageToast.show('Email is: ' + sText);

          // here comes the API request
          email.close();
        }
      }),
      endButton: new Button({
        text: 'סגירה',
        icon: 'sap-icon://decline',
        press: function () {
          email.close();
        }
      }),
      afterClose: function () {
        email.destroy();
      }
    });

    email.open();}
```

The error: [duplicate id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fn80i.png)

Many thanks!

Comment: I am studying UI5 at the moment. I think I read somewhere that destroy may leave the HTML elements in the dom. Maybe google for other cases related to use of fragment and destroy.

Answer (score 0):

you have attached the same event handler to "tap" and "press" events so sendToEmail is being called twice (and the second time the control with the same ID already exists)... remove "tap" as this is depreciated, so you should end up with:

```
<m:Button text="{i18n>RESULTS_CHANCES_SEND_EMAIL}"
      class="sapUiMediumMarginBegin results-button"
      press="sendToEmail"
      icon="sap-icon://email">
```